# Regular expression for replacing the strings in powershell

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have certain strings as given below

```
PS C:\Users> $S1="PS CUT (ZIP ONLY),  ALWAYS chose for MARTIO"
PS C:\Users> $s2="ZINO-IAS CUT"
PS C:\Users> $s3="ZINO-IPS CUT 2"
PS C:\Users> $s4="ZINO-IAS CUT4"
PS C:\Users> $s5="ZINO-IPS"
```

I want to replace above strings from the word **CUT** itself as given below

```
PS
ZINO-IAS
ZINO-IPS2
ZINO-IAS4
ZINO-IPS
```

Plase not that if there is a number after word **CUT** we are not removing that.

i tried the following code but it doesn't worked

```
PS C:\Users> $s5 -replace "CUT\s*\w*",""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
"\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
```

It checks for an optional number that comes after **CUT** and any spaces and uses that as the replacement (represented by **$1**). If the number doesn't exist, it replaces the entire match with an empty string.

Result:

```
[PS]> $s1 -replace "\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
PS
[PS]> $s2 -replace "\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
ZINO-IAS
[PS]> $s3 -replace "\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
ZINO-IPS2
[PS]> $s4 -replace "\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
ZINO-IAS4
[PS]> $s5 -replace "\s*CUT\s*(\d+)?.*","`$1"
ZINO-IPS
```